# ngx-formly update model not affected custom component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-formly

I use custorm component fields.

Everything works fine until I try to replace the model with another model.

the component of each field is not updated with the new value.

Nor did any event turn on

**the way i trying to change to model:**

```
this.model = this.data.model[this.currentRow];
```

**the html formly tag**

```
  <form class="formly" role="form" [formGroup]="form" >

    <formly-form #formly [(model)]="model" [fields]="fields" [form]="form" [options]="options">

    </formly-form>

  </form>

</div>
```

**app.model.ts**

```
FormlyModule.forRoot({
      types: [
        { name: 'customTextNumeric', component: VerticalNumericEditorComponent},        
        { name: 'customDatepicker', component: VerticalDatePickerComponent },
        { name: 'customSelect', component: VerticalSelectComponent },
.
```

.
.

**my custom component (for examle )**

```
 import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

import { FieldType } from '@ngx-formly/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroupDirective, NgForm, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ErrorStateMatcher } from '@angular/material/core';
import { SearchLabelService } from '../../tableHandle/search-label.service';

/** Error when invalid control is dirty, touched, or submitted. */

export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {

  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
        const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
        return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted));
      }
    }

@Component({
      selector: 'app-vertical-numeric-editor',
      templateUrl: './vertical-numeric-editor.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./vertical-numeric-editor.component.css']
    })

export class VerticalNumericEditorComponent extends FieldType {

  private validates = [];
      private initialValue;
      private value;



  private validateValues = { required: false, minLen: 0, maxLen: 99999999, pattern: '' };

  constructor(private labelSearch: SearchLabelService) {
        super();
        this.numericFormControl = new FormControl('', this.validates);
        console.log('constructor field:');
      }

  numericFormControl: FormControl;

  onInit() {
        console.log('oninit');
      }

  matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();

  ngOnInit() {
      }


  OnChanges(e) {
        console.log('on changes');
      }



  ngDoCheck() {
      }

  ngOnDestroy() {
      }

  get type() {
        return this.to.type || 'text';
      }
    }
```

Someone has an idea of how to update the component with the new value

Answer (score 0):

Check this issue in github:
https://github.com/formly-js/ngx-formly/issues/975

It seems it depends the way how you are updating your model (if it's just  updating one field of the model or not)